# Result of a function with parameters passed by name

Tags: parameter-passing

Consider the following pseudocode snippet:

```
int c = 2;
int bar(int a)
{
    c = c + 2;
    return a * 2;
}


int foo(void)
{
    return(bar(c + 1));
}
```

I'm asked to determine what the return value of foo(); will be, assuming that the language used passes all parameters by name.

My reasoning is that, since parameters are passed by name, `c+1` won't be evaluated when `bar(c+1)` is called, but only when the first instance of the formal parameter `a` is encountered in `bar`, that is in the `return a*2` line, after `bar` has modified the global variable `c`, so, since `c+1` has to be evaluated in the caller's environment, that is in `foo`'s environment and `foo` has only the global `c` in its scope it will be evaluated as `4+1`, giving a fine return value of `10`.

My doubt is whether this should be `6` instead, if I blindly apply a syntactical substitution rule, as passing by name requires the fifth line should be interpreted as `return c+1*2`, instead of `return (c+1)*2`, so what is the correct approach here?

For reference I'm using the definition of passing by name provided in section 7.1.2 of Programming Languages:Principles and Paradgigms by Gabbrielli and Martini